# Using Doctrine 2 without framework

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

i want to create a project and i want to use Doctrine 2. I installed it via Composer. I read the document and i created the "bootstrap.php" and "cli-config.php" in my root directory like the documentation said, but when i want to run the cli (ex: doctrine orm:schema-tool:create) it says my cli-config.php file is missing.

Here is my project structure:

```
doctrine_test
-- config
----(empty)
-- src
----(empty)
-- vendor (my composer vendor)
-- bootstrap.php
-- cli-config.php
-- composer.lock
-- composer.json
```

my composer file:

```
{
    "name": "serdartpkl/doctrine_test",
    "type": "project",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Serdar Tepekule",
            "email": "serdartpkl@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "doctrine/orm": "2.4.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "2.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

my bootstrap.php file:

```
<?php
// bootstrap.php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

// Create a simple "default" Doctrine ORM configuration for Annotations
$isDevMode = true;
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src"), $isDevMode);
// or if you prefer yaml or XML
//$config = Setup::createXMLMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/config/xml"), $isDevMode);
//$config = Setup::createYAMLMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/config/yaml"), $isDevMode);

// database configuration parameters
$conn = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_sqlite',
    'path' => __DIR__ . '/db.sqlite',
);

// obtaining the entity manager
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

my cli-config.php file:

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner;

// replace with file to your own project bootstrap
require_once 'bootstrap.php';

// replace with mechanism to retrieve EntityManager in your app
$entityManager = GetEntityManager();

return ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($entityManager);
```

i know its a lame question, but i spent 3 hours for fixing that. I use CMD and i am trying to run the doctrine cli like:

```
C:\>cd xampp/htdocs/doctrine_test
C:\xampp\htdocs\doctrine_test>cd vendor/bin
C:\xampp\htdocs\doctrine_test\vendor\bin>doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
You are missing a "cli-config.php" or "config/cli-config.php" file in your
project, which is required to get the Doctrine Console working. You can use the
following sample as a template:

<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner;

// replace with file to your own project bootstrap
require_once 'bootstrap.php';

// replace with mechanism to retrieve EntityManager in your app
$entityManager = GetEntityManager();

return ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($entityManager);
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to run this from the vendor/bin directory? Run from the doctrine test directory:  bin/vendor/doctrine ...